# How to capitalize the first word of user output data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I have a Vue application and I want to capitalize the user's name and type.

Also, I would like to change the date format like `5-May-2019`.

How can I do it in Laravel? Is there any function? It's showing the date in [this manner](https://ibb.co/2kffMvF).

```
  <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
                <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{user.type}}</td>
                <td>{{user.created_at}}</td>
  </tr>
```

I want [this result](https://ibb.co/n0QkD0R).

Comment: If you want answer for your laravel code, you need to post your backend code where you get this user data.

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel is from PHP language, you may use the function `ucfirst()` to capitalize the first letter of the word

For example:

```
$word = "john";
$new = ucfirst($word)
//outputs "John"
```

But if you want all the words of a string gets their first letter to be capitalized, use the function `ucwords()`

Comment: specifically, you may try `{{ucfirst(user.id)}}` and so on

Comment: `{{ ucfirst(user.id) }}` will not work because we are in a Vuejs component and that double mustaches will be replaced by the Vuejs template engine.

Comment: so the problem is not for Laravel, I think it's for VueJS / Javascript, might as well try `string.charAt(0).toUpperCase()` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Laravel `ucfirst()` in the view (not so cool)

or you can use Vue filters for both actions:

[Words filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)
[Date Filters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-filter-date-format)

Comment: I need this in laravel

Comment: then you will need to add it in the controller : $users = get all users -> $user->name = ucfirst($user->name && type); and  $user->created_at = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s')->format('j-M-Y');

Comment: sory for late but by adding this the data which is coming from db is disappears

Answer (score 0):

Please try php function to achieve the first character in capital

```
{{ ucfirst(user.id) }}
```

and for date you can use following

```
{{ date('d-M-y', strtotime($user.created_at)) }}
```

I hope this will helps you

Comment: `{{ ucfirst(user.id) }}` will not work because we are in a Vuejs component and that double mustaches will be replaced by the Vuejs template engine.

Comment: Ohh then will figure out something and pass it to you which will helps you

Comment: Great but well... I am not the author of the question!

Comment: Ohh i see, but may be you are with him/her that's why , ok no worry

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you get your users from Eloquent in the backend, you can use [`Collection#map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) to create a new collection with capitalized names and types, and with formatted dates.

- [`Carbon::createFromFormat`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) creates a Carbon instance from a given format and a string.
- [`Carbon->format`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) returns a date string into the given format.
- [`ucfirst()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) capitalizes a string.

**`Within controller:`**

```php
$users = $users->map(function($user) {
    $user->name = ucfirst($user->name);
    $user->type = ucfirst($user->type); // If "$user->type" returns a relationship between to table, you should adapt this line a bit.

    $user->created_at = \Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s')->format('j-M-Y');
});
```

Comment: sory for late but would u prefer to tel me where to write this in controller  coz it not working init    ::: 32338tP6t7YXNiUUgZyFXzx :::  this is address of pasteofcode.org u can check the complete code here

Answer (score 0):

Create filter

```
Vue.filter('capitalize', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  value = value.toString()
  return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
})
```

Use that filter

```
<td>{{user.name | capitalize}}</td>
```